SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when getting LinkedIn Token
I have a LinkedIn integration using NodeJS. I can get the authorization code from LinkedIn but when I try to get the access token on the redirect I get an error message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. 
Here is my auth file:
// Replace with your actual Client ID and Secret
const CLIENT_ID = MY_INFO_CHANGED;
const CLIENT_SECRET = MY_INFO_CHANGED;
const rURL = MY_INFO_CHANGED;
const SCOPE = MY_INFO_CHANGED;
qs = require("querystring");
const axios = require("axios");

const Authorization = () => {
  return encodeURI(
    `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&scope=${SCOPE}&redirect_uri=${rURL}`
  );
};

const Redirect = async (code) => {
  const payload = {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: rURL,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
  };
  const { data } = await axios({
    url: `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?${qs.stringify(
      payload
    )}`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return e;
    });
  return data;
};
module.exports = {
  Authorization,
  Redirect,
};


